# Adjust my one liner script - convert date/time string to [datetime] in powershell

Tags: powershell, date, time, powershell-4.0, ps1

I have this one liner:

```
Select-String -Path "C:\temp\TrackerLog.log" -Pattern "Program exited successfully" | Foreach-Object Line | Foreach {$_ -replace "\["} | %{ $line = $_.Split(' ') ; write-host $line[0] $line[1]}
```

The output is:

```
<p>14.03.2022 08:12:38</p>
<p>21.03.2022 12:36:36</p>
<p>29.03.2022 19:39:59</p>
<p>04.04.2022 11:05:44</p>
<p>11.04.2022 13:08:49</p>
<p>18.04.2022 09:48:50</p>
<p>27.04.2022 06:18:45</p>
<p>02.05.2022 10:41:26</p>
<p>10.05.2022 04:25:48</p>
<p>18.05.2022 04:56:44</p>
<p>26.05.2022 03:32:25</p>
<p>28.05.2022 10:18:00</p>
<p>04.06.2022 22:49:16</p>
<p>07.06.2022 02:31:08</p>
```

I would like to convert this string output to `[datetime]` with above one liner for further purpose. Could you please help me? Thank you very much.

Im now stucked, how to do it now.

Comment: Please format your code, see [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: I think replacing the `write-host` line with `[DateTime]::ParseExact("$($line[0]) $($line[1])", "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", $null)` will get you closer to what you want.  But you probably need to verify the formatting string is correctly matching date time pattern.

Comment: [DateTime]::ParseExact("14.03.2022 08:12:38", "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss",$null)